# Route discovery between master slave and slave slave

Tags: network-access, traceroute

I have a master node and different slave nodes. I want to perform traceroute from each slave to every other slave and master and send this route to master periodically with timestamp.

Bruteforce approach seems to be performing a traceroute from each slave to different slaves and then send to master.

I have tried calling `traceroute` using `subprocess` from my python script. But it takes a lot of time in generating the output and then sending the traceroute to master would again take a lot of time.

My main purpose is to store the routes in master and whenever any slaves fails i can get the latest route from these logs which i have stored in the master.

I have looked for other library tools as well such as `scapy` python library and `mtr`.

Any pointers on how to do this in best possible way ?

Thanks

Comment: Resource recommendations are off topic here. You can consider asking this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TeunVink edited the question

Comment: You could try to ask this question on [so], the programmer's site, where there are many network-savvy programmers. Programming is off-topic here. You should understand that recommendations are off-topic there, too.